# Problem deleting elements with 2 values in R list

Tags: r

I am trying to format a list such that I would have one word per value(I imported it from a very poor quality csv, and can't do much about improving the csv). I currently am trying to make it so that every element only has one value, however, the code I am currently using is not doing this, although I am not getting error messages.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```r
Terms <- []  #9020 elements with lengths 1, 2, and 3
for (x in 1:length(Terms)){
  if (Terms[[x]] %>% is.list()){

  term <-Terms[[x]]

  length(term) <- 1

  Terms[[x]]<-term
  }#should return list of same size, but only with elements of length 1
```

Any help figuring out what I could use to make it so that I can delete any second variables would be appreciated.

Comment: Unclear what your criteria is. You're trying to filter the list for elements with only 1 value? Or for every element, select only the 1st value? It would also help to have a reproducible sample of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to create a logical condition with `lengths` and then use that for subsetting the `list`

```
lst2 <- lst1[lengths(lst1) == 1]
```

If the intention is to get only the first element

```
lst2 <- lapply(lst1, `[`, 1)
```

NOTE: Assuming the `list` elements are `vector`ss